# Adjusting z values for all vertices in polylines in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, editing

Is there way in ArcEditor (10.0) to adjust all the vertices z values by an offset? (translate in z axis?)

I have many polylines which need to be lowered (eg: subtract 1m from every vertex z-value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could look at the [Adjust 3D Z](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000033000000) Geoprocessing Tool.

The help mentions

> adjust_value : A value to apply to all Z-values. To decrease the
>   Z-values for the entire feature class, enter a negative number. To
>   increase, enter a positive value.